# ElementNotInteractableException in selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape this site:https://www.wagr.com/mens-ranking, at the bottom right of the table there is a button to click to the next page, but selenium keeps throwing exceptions when I try to click it. The code below is what I'm using to click the button.

```
next = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.next > a:nth-child(1)')
next.click()
```

Here's a screenshot of the traceback:

[image: here's a screenshot of the exception traceback]
I can't understand why this isn't working, I'd be grateful for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

1. Handle the cookie pop up
2. Scroll down at the bottom of the page, so that the button could be visible

Here is a working code -

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

# options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
    options=options
)

with chrome_driver as driver:
    driver.implicitly_wait(15)
    driver.get('https://www.wagr.com/mens-ranking')
    time.sleep(3)

    # click cookie popup
    cookie_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/button")
    cookie_btn.click()
    time.sleep(0.3)
    
    # scrolling bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(2)

    next_btn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.next > a:nth-child(1)')  # li.next
    # next_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='next']")

    print("found and click next", next_btn.tag_name)
    next_btn.click()

    time.sleep(2)
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank You! I didn't realize I would need to scroll down.